# uninitialized constant name error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model as follows

app/models/views/def_usage.rb

```
class Abc
  class Def < ActiveRecord::Base

self.table_name = 'vSomeview'

  end
end
```

I am trying to create a factory girl for this

spec/factories/views/def_usage.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :def_usage, class: Abc::DefUsage do
 ......
  end
end
```

I am getting error `uninitialized constant Abc::DefUsage (NameError)`

I tried changing `class: Views::Abc::DefUsage` or `Views::DefUsage` but no luck. i am getting that error when i am trying to do `rails console`. why i am getting that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path needs to match your module/class hierarchy.

If you want your class to be in `app/models/views/def.rb`, then your class needs to be `Views::Def`.

If you want your class to be `Abc::Def`, your path needs to be `app/models/abc/def.rb`.

If you want your class name to be `DefUsage`, your file name needs to be `def_usage.rb`.

You can't use arbitrary paths and class names. They need to match if you want Rails to automatically load constants for you.

Comment: Thanks. So my class is in models/views/def_usage.rb and i am naming it in factory girl Views::DefUsage then it should work right? but getting same error

Comment: try just `models/def_usage.rb` and call the class `DefUsage` no real reason why you need to have it in a `views` folder

Comment: so when i moved it to models/abc/def_usage.rb and naming Abc::DefUsage in factory then it works. works for now. Thanks meagar and Carl